# Drupal - How to tell if node has been updated via UI form as oppose to programmatically?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am importing/updating nodes from a web service using node_save. One feature that I want to achieve is when the imported node is changed locally, it should not receive any further updates from the web service.

So, what I want to achieve is:

- Detect when a node has been updated
- If the update was carried out by a user submitting a form (as oppose to programmatically)
- Then flag that this node should receive no further updates form the web service (I don't need any assistance with this part)

I wanted to use hook_node_update but I'm not sure how to tell whether the update was carried out by a user submitting a form.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During CREATION of node by user (initial setup):
Create a hidden field for nodes with default value to be set to "**submitted by user**". As its a hidden field it wont be available in the node edit form, but still it will carry the default value with it.

UPDATING of node by user:
Use hook_form_alter to set the value of our hidden input to "**submitted by user**".

During CREATE/UPDATE of a node using webservice:
When creating a node programmatically update the hidden field value with "**submitted by webservice**".

Now in hook_node_update you can check for this hidden field value and take decisions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  How would I create a hidden field?  Via field API? Is there a specific module I need to install that allows creation of hidden fields?

Comment: As my installation necessarily contains display suite, i usually use that. I just happen to see there is a contrib module called Field Hidden (http://drupal.org/project/field_hidden) too.

Comment: Cool.  If I go ahead with your method I'll come back and mark as answer.